# Proving that Lebesgue measure is inner regular.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following theorem in measure theory.Here $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

**Theorem**

If $A\subset \mathbb R$ is such that given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a closed set $F\subset A$ such that $\mu(A\setminus F)<\epsilon$,then $\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset A$ and $K$ is compact $\}$.

I have proved it when $\mu(A)<\infty$.But I am stuck when $\mu(A)=\infty$.I only note that $A_n=[-n,n]\cap A$ can be useful.But I cannot proceed further.Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(A\cap [-n,n])\setminus ([-n,n]\cap F) \subseteq A\setminus F$. So $\mu (A\cap [-n,n])\setminus ([-n,n]\cap F)<\epsilon$ and the case you haev already covered shows that there is a  compact set $K \subseteq A\cap [-n,n]$ with $\mu (A\cap [-n,n]) <\epsilon +\mu(K)$. So $\mu (A\cap [-n,n])\leq \epsilon +\sup \{\mu (H): H \,\, \text {compact}, H \subseteq A\}$. (RHS does not depend on $n$).  Leting $n \to \infty$ we get $\mu (A)\leq \epsilon +\sup \{\mu (H): H \,\, \text {compact}, H \subseteq A\}$. Let $\epsilon \to 0$. The reverse inequality always holds.